# What should I edit to fix this design?

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I'm facing troubles to move down the button "Select" in the front-end view . I would like to change the position of the button below of the video section , help , please.

Is the problem using v-card-text? or maybe I'm missing some div tag , help.

[[image: Image of the problem]

```
 <v-tabs-items v-model="currentPage">
          <v-tab-item :key="0">
            <template>
              <v-card-text
                class="pa-5 vertical-hidden"
                :class="themeCommon.content"
                style="height: 67vh"
              >
                <div class="form-group">
                  <video id="id" controls="controls">
                    <source id="src" />
                  </video>
                  <v-row>
                    <v-col class="d-flex justify-center" cols="12">
                      <v-btn
                        class="accent-3 blue mb-1 mt-6"
                        dark
                        @click="pickFile"
                      >
                        Select File
                      </v-btn>
                    </v-col>
                  </v-row>
                  <input
                    v-show="false"
                    id="label"
                    ref="inputUpload"
                    type="file"
                    @change="load($event)"
                  />
                </div>
                <v-row>
                  <v-col class="d-flex justify-center" cols="12">
                    <v-text-field
                      v-if="setDisable()"
                      v-model="firstVideo"
                      append-outer-icon
                      class="Inputmodified"
                      label="Name the video"
                    />
                  </v-col>
                </v-row>
              </v-card-text>
              <v-card-actions
                class="pa-5"
                :class="themeCommon.background"
                @click="nextStep"
              >
                <v-btn
                  block
                  class="accent-3 blue"
                  dark
                  @click="sendVideo($event)"
                >
                  Save and Continue
                </v-btn>
              </v-card-actions>
            </template>
          </v-tab-item>
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrap your video tag inside the `v-row`; this will take the whole row for video and then the next row for your Select file button.

**Here is the example code:**

```
              <v-row>
                <video id="id" controls="controls">
                  <source id="src" />
                </video>
              </v-row>
              <v-row>
                <v-col class="d-flex justify-center" cols="12">
                  <v-btn
                    class="accent-3 blue mb-1 mt-6"
                    dark
                    @click="pickFile"
                  >
                    Select File
                  </v-btn>
                </v-col>
              </v-row>
```

Comment: Hi Riyaz, It didn't work , It looks like the image with that modification.